# does R create a new data frame in this situation or just a new column?

Tags: r

```
a <- data.frame(x=1:100, y = 100:1)
b <- a # just the reference is copied
b$y <- 1:100 # is a new data frame created. Or just a new column, i.e. both a and b still reference the same x column?
```

So I know that r only copy on modify, but I am not sure which parts get copied when only some parts are modified.

Answer (score 2):

You can see for yourself how much copying happens using `tracemem`:

```
> a <- data.frame(x=1:100, y = 100:1)
> tracemem(a)
[1] "<0x7fdf7ff93248>"
> b <- a
> b$y <- 1:100
tracemem[0x7fdf7ff93248 -> 0x7fdf82e58088]: 
tracemem[0x7fdf82e58088 -> 0x7fdf82e57dc8]: $<-.data.frame $<- 
tracemem[0x7fdf82e57dc8 -> 0x7fdf82e57d88]: $<-.data.frame $<-
```

Answer (score 1):

According to `dplyr::location` *just a new column - a and b still reference the same x column* (R 3.6.1).

```
a <- data.frame(x=1:100, y = 100:1)

b <- a
dplyr::location(a)
#<0x55dce5555688>
#Variables:
# * x:         <0x55dce68d7c98> ##
# * y:         <0x55dce68d7bb8> ##
#Attributes:
# * names:     <0x55dce55558c8>
# * class:     <0x55dce68d3160>
# * row.names: <0x55dce5718b58>
dplyr::location(b)
#<0x55dce5555688>
#Variables:
# * x:         <0x55dce68d7c98> ##
# * y:         <0x55dce68d7bb8> ##
#Attributes:
# * names:     <0x55dce55558c8>
# * class:     <0x55dce68d3160>
# * row.names: <0x55dce654e5b8>

b$y <- 1:100
dplyr::location(a)
#<0x55dce5555688>
#Variables:
# * x:         <0x55dce68d7c98> ##
# * y:         <0x55dce68d7bb8> ##
#Attributes:
# * names:     <0x55dce55558c8>
# * class:     <0x55dce68d3160>
# * row.names: <0x55dce65708a0>
dplyr::location(b)
#<0x55dce5b82378>
#Variables:
# * x:         <0x55dce68d7c98> ##
# * y:         <0x55dce65635c0> ##
#Attributes:
# * names:     <0x55dce55558c8>
# * row.names: <0x55dce65d3040>
# * class:     <0x55dce68d3160>

dplyr::changes(a, b)
#Changed variables:
#          old            new           
#y         0x55bb19b3fbb8 0x55bb1a3636d0
#
#Changed attributes:
#          old            new           
#row.names 0x55bb197c3b38 0x55bb197cc190
```

Same result when using `.Internal(inspect(a))` and `.Internal(inspect(b))`.